# Why is half my webpage unclickable when I am using a stick up nav menu and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a menu on my website that is suppose to stick to the top of the screen as you scroll down the page, It works perfectly, but there is one problem. I cannot click any were on the top 50% of the screen making the website unusable. `http://streamportal.comuv.com/StreamPortal/Test.html` this is a test copy (not the true site). can someone take a look at this and tell me what to do? If you need any more info from me please let me know.

This is what I a using to  make the menu stay stick while scrolling, thanks to the help of gfrobenius, `http://jsfiddle.net/wHF97/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this:

```
 <div style="height:1000px"> //Remove the height
 </div>
```

It's the div after `id="cssmenu"`

Comment: Thank you! removing it did not work, but I was able to turn it to "height:25px" on that same line and it works perfectly now :).